# TPopupmenu Ownerdraw

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, popupmenu, ownerdrawn

i set the Popupmenu OwnerDraw property True but there is no "OnOwnerDraw" event  neither in the object inspector nor .OnOwnerDraw property in the code !

using Delphi 2010

[image]

[image]

Comment: There is `TMenuItem.OnDrawItem`; each menu item gets it own (or shared) event

Comment: @DavidA that's right i found the event in ".Items" thanks, please place it as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [`TMenuItem.OnDrawItem`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Vcl.Menus.TMenuItem.OnDrawItem) each menu item gets it own (or shared) event.